# Notifications not working with ios8 - Pushwoosh + phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, pushwoosh

4 apps in apple store and android market created with pushwoosh + phonegap build. Notifications works good on all devices except for new ios8. why? is sometheing changed? I used these 2 files:
Pushnotification.js

```
(function(cordova) {

    function PushNotification() {}

    // Call this to register for push notifications and retreive a deviceToken
    PushNotification.prototype.registerDevice = function(config, success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "registerDevice", config ? [config] : []);
    };

    // Call this to set tags for the device
    PushNotification.prototype.setTags = function(config, success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "setTags", config ? [config] : []);
    };

    // Call this to send geo location for the device
    PushNotification.prototype.sendLocation = function(config, success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "sendLocation", config ? [config] : []);
    };

    PushNotification.prototype.onDeviceReady = function() {
        cordova.exec(null, null, "PushNotification", "onDeviceReady", []);
    };

    // Call this to get tags for the device
    PushNotification.prototype.getTags = function(success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "getTags", []);
    };

    //Android Only----
    PushNotification.prototype.unregisterDevice = function(success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "unregisterDevice", []);
    };

    //config params: {msg:"message", seconds:30, userData:"optional"}
    PushNotification.prototype.createLocalNotification = function(config, success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "createLocalNotification", config ? [config] : []);
    };

    PushNotification.prototype.clearLocalNotification = function() {
        cordova.exec(null, null, "PushNotification", "clearLocalNotification", []);
    };

    //advanced background task to track device position and not drain the battery
    PushNotification.prototype.startGeoPushes = function(success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "startGeoPushes", []);
    };

    PushNotification.prototype.stopGeoPushes = function(success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "stopGeoPushes", []);
    };

    //sets multi notification mode on
    PushNotification.prototype.setMultiNotificationMode = function(success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "setMultiNotificationMode", []);
    };

    //sets single notification mode
    PushNotification.prototype.setSingleNotificationMode = function(success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "setSingleNotificationMode", []);
    };

    //type: 0 default, 1 no sound, 2 always
    PushNotification.prototype.setSoundType = function(type, success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "setSoundType", [type]);
    };  

    //type: 0 default, 1 no vibration, 2 always
    PushNotification.prototype.setVibrateType = function(type, success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "setVibrateType", [type]);
    };  

    PushNotification.prototype.setLightScreenOnNotification = function(on, success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "setLightScreenOnNotification", [on]);
    };

    //set to enable led blinking when notification arrives and display is off
    PushNotification.prototype.setEnableLED = function(on, success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "setEnableLED", [on]);
    };

    //{goal:'name', count:3} (count is optional)
    PushNotification.prototype.sendGoalAchieved = function(config, success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "sendGoalAchieved", config ? [config] : []);
    };

    //Android End----

    //iOS only----
    PushNotification.prototype.startLocationTracking = function(backgroundMode, success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "startLocationTracking", backgroundMode ? [{mode : backgroundMode}] : []);
    };

    PushNotification.prototype.stopLocationTracking = function(success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "stopLocationTracking", []);
    };

    // Call this to get a detailed status of remoteNotifications
    PushNotification.prototype.getRemoteNotificationStatus = function(callback) {
        cordova.exec(callback, callback, "PushNotification", "getRemoteNotificationStatus", []);
    };

    // Call this to set the application icon badge
    PushNotification.prototype.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber = function(badgeNumber, callback) {
        cordova.exec(callback, callback, "PushNotification", "setApplicationIconBadgeNumber", [{badge: badgeNumber}]);
    };

    // Call this to clear all notifications from the notification center
    PushNotification.prototype.cancelAllLocalNotifications = function(callback) {
        cordova.exec(callback, callback, "PushNotification", "cancelAllLocalNotifications", []);
    };
    //iOS End----

    // Event spawned when a notification is received while the application is active
    PushNotification.prototype.notificationCallback = function(notification) {
        var ev = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        ev.notification = notification;
        ev.initEvent('push-notification', true, true, arguments);
        document.dispatchEvent(ev);
    };

    cordova.addConstructor(function() {
        if(!window.plugins) window.plugins = {};
        window.plugins.pushNotification = new PushNotification();
    });

})(window.cordova || window.Cordova || window.PhoneGap);
```

And app.js

```
    function registerPushwooshIOS() {
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

    //push notifications handler
    document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
                var notification = event.notification;
                //navigator.notification.alert(notification.aps.alert);

                //to view full push payload
                //navigator.notification.alert(JSON.stringify(notification));

                //reset badges on icon
                pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0);
              });

    pushNotification.registerDevice({alert:true, badge:true, sound:true, pw_appid:"69620-5C1D0", appname:"Maxistore"},
                                    function(status) {
                                        var deviceToken = status['deviceToken'];
                                        console.warn('registerDevice: ' + deviceToken);
                                        onPushwooshiOSInitialized(deviceToken);
                                    },
                                    function(status) {
                                        console.warn('failed to register : ' + JSON.stringify(status));
                                        navigator.notification.alert(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
                                    });

    //reset badges on start
    pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0);
}

function onPushwooshiOSInitialized(pushToken)
{
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    //retrieve the tags for the device
    pushNotification.getTags(function(tags) {
                                console.warn('tags for the device: ' + JSON.stringify(tags));
                             },
                             function(error) {
                                console.warn('get tags error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                             });

    //start geo tracking. PWTrackSignificantLocationChanges - Uses GPS in foreground, Cell Triangulation in background. 
    pushNotification.startLocationTracking('PWTrackSignificantLocationChanges',
                                    function() {
                                           console.warn('Location Tracking Started');
                                    });
}

function registerPushwooshAndroid() {

    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

    //push notifications handler
    document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
                var title = event.notification.title;
                var userData = event.notification.userdata;

                //dump custom data to the console if it exists
                if(typeof(userData) != "undefined") {
                    console.warn('user data: ' + JSON.stringify(userData));
                }

                //and show alert
                //navigator.notification.alert(title);

                //stopping geopushes
                pushNotification.stopGeoPushes();
              });

    //projectid: "GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID", appid : "PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID"
    pushNotification.registerDevice({ projectid: "863823034249", appid : "69620-5C1D0" },
                                    function(token) {
                                        alert(token);
                                        //callback when pushwoosh is ready
                                        onPushwooshAndroidInitialized(token);
                                    },
                                    function(status) {
                                        alert("failed to register: " +  status);
                                        console.warn(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
                                    });
 }

function onPushwooshAndroidInitialized(pushToken)
{
    //output the token to the console
    console.warn('push token: ' + pushToken);

    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

    pushNotification.getTags(function(tags) {
                            console.warn('tags for the device: ' + JSON.stringify(tags));
                         },
                         function(error) {
                            console.warn('get tags error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                         });


    //set multi notificaiton mode
    //pushNotification.setMultiNotificationMode();
    //pushNotification.setEnableLED(true);

    //set single notification mode
    //pushNotification.setSingleNotificationMode();

    //disable sound and vibration
    //pushNotification.setSoundType(1);
    //pushNotification.setVibrateType(1);

    pushNotification.setLightScreenOnNotification(false);

    //goal with count
    //pushNotification.sendGoalAchieved({goal:'purchase', count:3});

    //goal with no count
    //pushNotification.sendGoalAchieved({goal:'registration'});

    //setting list tags
    //pushNotification.setTags({"MyTag":["hello", "world"]});

    //settings tags
    pushNotification.setTags({deviceName:"hello", deviceId:10},
                                    function(status) {
                                        console.warn('setTags success');
                                    },
                                    function(status) {
                                        console.warn('setTags failed');
                                    });

    function geolocationSuccess(position) {
        pushNotification.sendLocation({lat:position.coords.latitude, lon:position.coords.longitude},
                                 function(status) {
                                      console.warn('sendLocation success');
                                 },
                                 function(status) {
                                      console.warn('sendLocation failed');
                                 });
    };

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function geolocationError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    function getCurrentPosition() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError);
    }

    //greedy method to get user position every 3 second. works well for demo.
//  setInterval(getCurrentPosition, 3000);

    //this method just gives the position once
//  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError);

    //this method should track the user position as per Phonegap docs.
//  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, { maximumAge: 3000, enableHighAccuracy: true });

    //Pushwoosh Android specific method that cares for the battery
    pushNotification.startGeoPushes();
}

 function initPushwoosh() {
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    if(device.platform == "Android")
    {
        registerPushwooshAndroid();
        pushNotification.onDeviceReady();
    }

    if(device.platform == "iPhone" || device.platform == "iOS")
    {
        registerPushwooshIOS();
        pushNotification.onDeviceReady();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The push notification interface changed in iOS8. If your third-party library hasn't been updated to adapt, push notifications will likely fail.

Background:
Previously, registering for notifications was done with

```
-[UIApplication registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:]
```

As of iOS8, it is now done with:

```
-[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:]
-[UIApplication registerForRemoteNotifications]
```

Comment: Tnx for your answer, i used last version of phonegap...so i think that error is in 2 files i used. No one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the pushwoosh [post](https://www.pushwoosh.com/blog/)

> Due to multiple support requests about iOS 8 we thought it’d be good to also shed some light here in our Blog. Currently, there are two version of Pushwoosh iOS SDK:
>
> iOS 7 SDK – must be compiled with Xcode v.5 – does not support latest features introduced in iOS 8;
>
> iOS 8 SDK – must be compiled with Xcode v.6
>
> So, applications compiled with iOS 7 SDK in Xcode v.5 will continue working properly on devices running iOS 8 due to its compatibility. If you use Pushwoosh iOS 8 SDK, you must compile your app with Xcode v.6.

You can download it [here](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-ios-sdk/tree/master/Framework_iOS7/Pushwoosh.framework)